# Main application not responding to events?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

I have a dll/assembly and a main application that are separate projects. This is C# VS2008.

The dll/assembly that periodically checks if some particular string is written in a .txt file; Once it finds the string, it will fire an event:

```
 public delegate void IjmFinishedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

 public class FijiLauncherControl
{
    System.Timers.Timer _logFileCheckTimer;       // log file status check timer; reading every 1/4 second 

   public event IjmFinishedEventHandler IjmFinished;

    // Invoke the Changed event; called whenever list changes
    protected virtual void OnIjmFinished(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IjmFinished != null)
            IjmFinished(this, e);

    }

 void _logFileCheckTimer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)  // tick check task finish
    {
        if (_processOn && IsLogOn)
        {
            try
            {
                _processFinished = CheckStatuts();

                if (_processFinished)
                {          
                    OnIjmFinished(EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }   

    public bool CheckStatuts()  // check if string is written in file
        {
            bool ret;
            var lastLine = File.ReadAllLines(_logFile).Last();

            ret = String.Compare(lastLine, _doneStr) == 0 ? true : false;

            return ret;
        }

  public FijiLauncherControl()   //start the timer
    {
        _logFileCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(250);  // read log 4 times per sec 
        _logFileCheckTimer.Enabled = true;
        _logFileCheckTimer.Elapsed += new        System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(_logFileCheckTimer_Elapsed);
        }
    }
```

And in my main application, I added this dll as a reference, and basically trying to monitor the event (from the dll I guess) whenever is triggered by the particular string gets written in to the .txt file:

```
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
            private FijiLauncherControl _fl;


        void Window1_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _fl.IjmFinished -= new IjmFinishedEventHandler(_fl_IjmFinished);

        }

        void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            _fl.IjmFinished += new IjmFinishedEventHandler(_fl_IjmFinished);
        }

        void _fl_IjmFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _vm.IjmFinished = true;
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();            
        }    

    }
```

However, at

```
void _fl_IjmFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _vm.IjmFinished = true;
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();            
        }
```

it never responds even though the particular string did get written in the .txt. It seems as if the event never gets fired in from the assembly. But if I set a breakpoint inside the assembly,  at

It's weird, that I have to set the breakpoint at  `if (_processFinished)`, then it will hit  `OnIjmFinished(EventArgs.Empty)`; but it I put the breakpoint at  `OnIjmFinished(EventArgs.Empty);` it does not hit the break point.!

So the whole problem looks to me that the assembly can fire the event, but the main application somehow fail to receive it. I am wondering where I did wrong to mess this up? Anyone can give any suggestions? I highly appreciate any opinion.

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint inside the _OnIjmFinished_ method, to make sure the event is not null and it actually gets fired?

Comment: It's weird, that I have to set the breakpoint at  if (_processFinished), then it will hit  OnIjmFinished(EventArgs.Empty); but it I put the breakpoint at  OnIjmFinished(EventArgs.Empty); it does not hit the break point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `Window1_Loaded` is actually wired up, if you registered this through the windows forms designer, it can sometimes get lost when the code behind is re-generated.

If you do find all references on `Window1_Loaded` and there are no references then that's your problem, just go into the designer and re-connect the event handler to the `WindowLoaded` event.

Also, you can use the `EventHandler` delegate in `System` instead of declaring your own:

```
public event EventHandler IjmFinished;
```

And your raise event method isn't thread safe, you should use this pattern instead:

```
protected virtual void OnIjmFinished(EventArgs e)
{
    var finished = IjmFinished;

    if (finished != null) { finished(this, e); }
}
```

The way you currently do it allows a subscriber on another thread to unregister between your `if` and raising the event which would result in you getting a hard to debug `NullReferenceException`